# Permanently disable point stick

Tags: command-line, 20.04, mouse, touchpad, xinput

I have a faulty point stick on my old Dell latitude E6500 running Ubuntu 20.04. I have a temporary fix where I run `xinput --disable *device id*`, which works great but I have to run this every time I startup the computer.

I know I could use the Startup Applications to run the command every time the computer starts up but the issue with that is the device id always changes.

example when I run `xinput` I get this.

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad          id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick             id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HID 413c:8157                             id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

and for now the device id I need is 12 so I run `xinput --disable 12` which works fine. But when I restart the device id could change to 13 and id 12 would go to the touchpad which I want enabled.

So running `xinput --disable 12` every time on startup will either disable the touchpad or the point stick.

I'd like to know if there's another way to permanently disable the point stick or maybe a script which finds only the point stick id and disables it everytime I start up. Thanks

Comment: You should be able to do something like `id=$(xinput list --id-only 'AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick')` to obtain the id

Comment: This also works, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a one liner script for the startup to disable a touchpad on one of our computers.  The id for the touchpad also changed every boot.

```
xinput --disable `xinput list | grep Synaptics | awk -F'id=' '{print$2}' | awk -F' ' '{print$1}'`
```

You can change the `Synaptics` to  `Stick` and it should work

Comment: Thanks. this works great